# Why javascript bind doesn't work

Tags: javascript, bind

function:

```
function talk(){ 
        console.log(this.name + " dice: ");
}

var Person = function(name, surname){
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}

var p = new Person("Mark", "Red");

talk.bind(p);
```

what's wrong with bind?

Comment: Worth adding, for anyone following this question, that you can get "one-time" binding by using a function's `call` or `apply` method. So another solution to the above issue is to replace `.bind` with `.call` (here `talk.call(p)`).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It does work, talk.bind(p) returns the bound function:

`talk.bind(p)();`

Answer (score 8):

Nothing is wrong with `bind()`-- it's just not being used correctly. `bind()` *returns a new function* which is bound to the object specified. You still need to execute that function:

```
function talk(){ 
        console.log(this.name + " dice: ");
}

var Person = function(name, surname){
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}

var p = new Person("Mark", "Red");

var markTalks = talk.bind(p);

markTalks();    // logs properly
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), it returns a function which is bound to the object passed as argument. So you need to invoke it like this

```
talk.bind(p)();
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, bind appears to work as expected but it needs invoking.

Another solution that is a bit cleaner, especially if each 'Person' object needs the ability to talk, would be to include the function in the person constructor:

```
var Person = function(name, surname){
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.talk = function(){
        console.log(this.name + " dice: ");
    }
}

var p = new Person("Mark", "Red");

p.talk();
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amspianist/J5BSh/

Answer (score 1):

[call or apply](https://medium.com/@leonardobrunolima/javascript-tips-apply-vs-call-vs-bind-d738a9e8b4e1) can be used instead of `bind`

`talk.call(p);`
`talk.apply(p);`